Problem with build in webcam after installation of Ubuntu 24.04
after I upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 my webcam doesn't working.
I see the camera in lspci but application can't find it.
I use laptop ThinkBook 16 G6 IRL.
Please help?

lspci, lsusb, lshw needed output of dmesg would also be nice
